# Use wildcard in loop folderpath

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a batch which is sorting out pictures in different folders. Which is working fine

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
         move "%%a" "K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\%%b/subfolder/%%c" >nul
      )
)
```

Now I need to change a bit, but it doesn't want to work. So the first parts of the jpg is only the parts of the name of the sub folder the rest is unknown.

The batch would be something like this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.jpg) do (
   echo processing "%%a"
      for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
         move "%%a" "K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\%%b*/subfolder/%%c" >nul
      )
)
```

for example I would like to move a picture: `abc$pic1.jpg` to

```
K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\abc12345\subfolder\pic1.jpg
```

So probably I do need to use * instead 12345. There is always one abc destination folder but I never know what is the ending..

Comment: Start with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. Look for the target folder explicitly: `for /d %%d in ("K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\%%b*") do set "TARGETFOLDER=%%~d"`, then use `!TARGETFOLDER!`. Wildcards do not work in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do not use `/` as the path separator, it is `\` in Windows!

Wildcards can only be used in the very last element of a path, so something like `K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\abc*\subfolder\pic1.jpg` cannot be used.

You could wrap a [`for /D` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) around your `move` command line, like this:

```cmd
@echo off
for %%a in ("*.jpg") do (
    echo processing "%%~a"
    for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=$" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
        for /D %%d in ("K:\folder\subfolder\subfolder\%%b*") do (
            move "%%~a" "%%~d\subfolder\%%c" > nul
        )
    )
)
```